# Elasticsearch Nest DeleteMany fails to infer type

Tags: elasticsearch, nest

How can I get DeleteMany to work in Nest?

I have the following code:

```
var deleteResult = _client.DeleteMany<MyType>(ids.Select(x => new MyType { id = x }));
```

I have a default index set, which is working fine, but this code returns an error because the type is not defined:

```
Elasticsearch.Net.ElasticsearchClientException: Request failed to execute. Call: Status code 400 from: POST /_bulk?pretty=true&error_trace=true. ServerError: Type: action_request_validation_exception Reason: "Validation Failed: 1: type is missing;2: type is missing; etc"
```

Looking at the [Nest code on github](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-net/blob/master/src/Nest/Document/Multiple/Bulk/ElasticClient-DeleteMany.cs) it implies that the type should be inferred, and the comments suggest that I can also supply it, though I can't see how.

Comment: Which version of NEST and elasticsearch are you using?

Comment: @Rob Elasticsearch 6.3 and NEST 7 - just figured it out myself!